# Most efficient way to include hundreds of the same pspicture

Tags: floats, pstricks

I have a pspicture involving an ornament from the psvectorian package:

```
\begin{pspicture}(0mm,10mm)(0mm, 10mm)
\rput[tl](5mm,5mm){\psvectorian[height=5mm]{10}}
\end{pspicture}
```

I am using this snippet multiple times in each page of a long document. As it stands right now I've made this a macro and executed it everywhere I need the ornament, but it is very very slow to compile and prone to rendering errors. At each compile some of the graphics would be randomly transposed or reflected elsewhere, which would be fixed the next time I compile with other issues poping out elsewhere, so I end up compiling a couple of times and stitching the correctly rendered pages together.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but don't know how.

Comment: In your preamble do something like `\newbox\MyPSbox\setbox\MyPSbox\hbox{<your pspicture>}`. Then in your document use `\usebox\MyPSbox` instead of your macro. (*untested*)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. With it I'd have tested the above suggestion and would have made sure that it works.

Comment: `\newsavebox\mybox\sbox\mybox{\begin{pspicture}...\end{pspicture}}\newcommand\usemybox{\usebox{\mybox}}` and then `\usemybox` wherever you need it. Or you can automate it if you want it at the same place on every page or something.

Comment: You've tagged this 'floats'. If the things are intended to float, that's obviously rather different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an answer based on my comment:

Compare the time needed for compilation of the two below documents:

**With box**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{psvectorian}

\newsavebox\MyPSbox
\sbox\MyPSbox
  {%
    \begin{pspicture}(0mm,10mm)(0mm, 10mm)
    \rput[tl](5mm,5mm){\psvectorian[height=5mm]{10}}
    \end{pspicture}%
  }
\newcommand*\mypspic{\usebox\MyPSbox}

\newcounter{testcount}

\begin{document}
\loop\ifnum\value{testcount}<100
\stepcounter{testcount}%
\mypspic\par
\repeat
\end{document}
```

**Without box**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{psvectorian}

\newcommand*\mypspic
  {%
    \begin{pspicture}(0mm,10mm)(0mm, 10mm)
    \rput[tl](5mm,5mm){\psvectorian[height=5mm]{10}}
    \end{pspicture}%
  }

\newcounter{testcount}

\begin{document}
\loop\ifnum\value{testcount}<100
\stepcounter{testcount}%
\mypspic\par
\repeat
\end{document}
```

On my machine the boxed version took 0.18s to compile, while the latter version took 0.42s.

Comment: Ending lines with `\\ ` is a bad habit to model. So is use of `\def`, `\newbox` and `\newcount` as you are not doing any checks at all.

Comment: @cfr satisfied?

Comment: Since that's what I said in my comment, obviously :-).

Comment: *Off-topic*: @cfr is that dad who always wants the best for his children, although sometimes it's hard to follow him `;)`.

Comment: @manooooh Assumptions are dangerous online.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\newsavebox\PSBox
\sbox\PSBox{\rule{0pt}{5mm}%
    \rput[tl](5mm,5mm){\psvectorian[height=5mm]{10}}}

\begin{document}
    \psforeach{\iA}{1,2,..,100}{\usebox\PSBox\par}
\end{document}
```

only `latex`:

> real  0m0,487s user   0m0,403s sys    0m0,049s

with additional ? dvips`and`ps2pdf`

> real  0m1,311s user   0m1,004s sys    0m0,102s

Comment: How is this an answer? You don't gain speed with leaving out the `pspicture` environment. This performs roughly as bad as the second document in my answer (~0.4 s compilation time) compared to ~0.16 s compilation time if you box stuff up and use the box in the loop. I think you misunderstood the question, it's not about how to code efficiently place 100 pictures but about compilation performance.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude or something, but now it basically looks like a duplicate of my answer, as the bottom line is "use a box" (you posted the complete output of `time`, though).